# How to connect spinner item selection to an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-spinner

I have an app where there is a spinner at the top of the layout and some text fields below it and a button at the bottom named "RESULT". In the spinner I have put name of different formulas which when selected must act upon the numbers in the text field and when the RESULT button is pressed a new layout with the result must be displayed.
As of now I have created activity for each formula in spinner. I don't know how to connect spinner formula selection with the formula activity.
Being a beginner I have searched for every possible solution here but couldn't find it.
Can anyone help me with a piece of code.

---

**I applied the solution as shown below**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.selective);
final Class[] clazz={Srkt.class,Binkhorst.class,Srk2.class,Holladay.class};
spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.formulae);
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(Selection.this,clazz[pos]);
        startActivity(i);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    });
```

---

**the logcat shows following errors**

```
    12-28 15:17:41.336: E/Trace(768): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Srkt}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.example.iolcalci.Srkt.onCreate(Srkt.java:34)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-28 15:17:44.554: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  ... 11 more
```

---

**Srkt code here**

```
public class Srkt extends Activity{
EditText k1_e,k2_e,al_e,alconst_e;
float k1,k2,al,al_const;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     float Rcor;
     float Lcor;
     float Crwdest;
     float Avg_k;
     float Corneal_H;
     float Acd_Const;
     float Offset;
     float Acd_Est;
     float Na=(float) 1.34;
     float C2=(float) 0.33;
     float C3;
     float C4;
     float C5;
     float C6;
     float C8;
     float C9;
     float Iolam;


    k1_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.k1_editText);
    k1=Float.parseFloat(k1_e.getText().toString());
    k2_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.k2_editText);
    k2=Float.parseFloat(k2_e.getText().toString());
    al_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.al_editText);//line 37
    al=Float.parseFloat(al_e.getText().toString());
    alconst_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.al_const_editText);
    al_const=Float.parseFloat(alconst_e.getText().toString()); 


    Avg_k=(k1+k2)/2;
    float Rcor1=(float)(337.5/Avg_k);Rcor=Round(Rcor1,2);

    if(al<=24.2){
        Lcor=al;
    }else{
        Lcor=(float) (-3.446+1.716*al-0.0237*(al*al));
    }Lcor=Round(Lcor,2);
    Crwdest=(float) (-5.41+0.58412*Lcor+0.098*Avg_k);Crwdest=Round(Crwdest,2);
    Corneal_H=(float) (Rcor-(Math.sqrt(Rcor*Rcor-Crwdest*Crwdest/4)));Corneal_H=Round(Corneal_H,2);
    Acd_Const=(float) (0.62467*al_const-68.747);
    Offset=(float) (Acd_Const-3.336);Offset=Round(Offset,2);
    Acd_Est=(Corneal_H+Offset); float Acd_Est1=Round(Acd_Est,2);
    C3=(float) (0.97971*al+0.65696);C3=Round(C3,2);     
    C4=C3-Acd_Est1;C4=Round(C4,2);
    C5=(float) ((Na*Rcor)-(C2*Acd_Est)); C5=Round(C5, 2);
    C6=(float) ((Na*Rcor1)-(C2*C3));
    C8=(float) ((12*C6)+(C3*Rcor1));C8=Round(C8,2);
    C9=(float) ((12*C5)+(Acd_Est*Rcor1));C9=Round(C9,2);
    Iolam=(float) ((1336*(C6-(0.001*C8*0)))/(C4*(C5-(0.001*0*C9))));Iolam=Round(Iolam,2);                       /*Desired Refraction not taken*/
    }

    public static float Round(float Rval, int Rpl) {
          float p = (float)Math.pow(10,Rpl);
          Rval = Rval * p;
          float tmp = Math.round(Rval);
          return (float)tmp/p;
          }
```

---

**I have added this line selection activity**

```
k1_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.k1_editText);
k1=Float.parseFloat(k1_e.getText().toString());
```

---

**updated logcat shows**

```
    12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Selection}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:289)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.example.iolcalci.Selection.onCreate(Selection.java:25)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-29 07:16:54.642: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  ... 11 more
```

**whats the problem and how how am i supposed to deal with it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As of now I have created activity for each formula in spinner. I don't
>   know how to connect spinner formula selection with the formula
>   activity.

Have an array of `Class` holding the name of each of those `Activities`(the order will be the order of the formulas as they appear in the `Spinner`):

```
Class[] clazz = {NameOfActivity1.class, NameOfActivity2.class /*etc*/};
```

You'll then have a `int` field(*mSelected*) which will be updated by the `OnItemSelectedListener` on the `Spinner`(*mSelected = position*). When it's time to show the results just use the *mSelected* field along with the array above to start the proper activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, clazz[mSelected]);
```

Also, depending on what you show in the results activities, you may want to have a single results activity which will hold an array with the formulas. To this activity you'll pass an `int` value(in the `Intent`) of the currently selected formula from the `Spinner` and you'll use that to build the proper result output.

Proper implementation in the `Selection` activity:

```
private int mSelected = -1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.selective);
final Class[] clazz={Srkt.class,Binkhorst.class,Srk2.class,Holladay.class};
spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.formulae);
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        mSelected = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
       mSelected = -1;
    }
    });
// find the results Button and set a OnClickListener where you'll do the calculation
Button resultsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_results_button);
resultsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnCLickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         // In here you'll do the calculation
         // you know the selected formula from the value of mSelected
         // after you do the calculation you will start the proper results activity using the clazz array and mSelected
        // you would also pass the results you calculated in the Intent used to start the new activity
    }

});
```

Comment: @AhamBrahmaasmi You have a `NullPointerException` at line `34` in the `Srkt` class(which I assume is one of the results classes!?!). I can't help if you don't show the code for that class's `onCreate` method(specify which one is the line `34`).

Comment: it is not the result class..it is calculation class .It does not have any layout

Comment: @AhamBrahmaasmi An Activity should represent a screen of the app and shouldn't be used as an intermediate class as you do(the exception is normal as you search for `EditText` which aren't in the activity(you have no layout)). Please revisit my answer. Do the calculations in the `Selection` activity and start the new activity when clicking the results button.

Comment: @AhamBrahmaasmi The exception is pretty clear, you're trying to parse as a float an empty string which will fail. If you have the lines `Float.parseFloat` in the `onCreate` method this will throw the exception as the `EditTexts` are empty at that moment. See my edited answer.

Comment: just a doubt ! even the onlick method is inside oncreate right. will it not pose same problem?

Comment: @AhamBrahmaasmi Yes, what I posted(including the `OnClickListener`) is in the activity's `onCreate` method.

Comment: i have put the parse code in button onclicklistner method but syill wen i click button same error.any clue?

Comment: @AhamBrahmaasmi Make sure you have proper float numbers in the `EditTexts` when you try to parse it with `Float.parse`.

Comment: problem is i cant enter any input to k1 and k2 as its not been showing on the screen. wat might be the prob?

Comment: @AhamBrahmaasmi Did you set the content view? is the layout file properly built(if the views are added in a `LinearLayout` did you set the orientation to vertical?)?